# Scanning barcode using Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, barcode-scanner

I would like develop an application in asp.net 5 / Angular2 and I have a problem with scanning barcodes.

I have my component using typeScript :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'barcode-scanner',
    templateUrl: 'app/scan.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class ScanComponent implements OnInit {
    barcode: string;

    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() { }

    onKey(event: any) {
        this.barcode = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

and my html template (scan.html):

```
<barcode-scanner>
    <div class="container">
        <header><h1>My App title</h1></header>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" (keyup)="onKey($event)" autofocus />
            <p>barcode: {{ barcode }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</barcode-scanner>
```

It's working, but only when the input is displayed on the screen, and focused.
Is there a way to do that with a hidden input ? (I've tried a `input type="hidden"`, and also an `input type="text"` with a `display:none` style's attribute but in the both case It didn't works.

Also, is it possible to catch the `keypress` event on the document ? and not on a specified input ?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to global events by adding the event target as prefix `target:event`. `target` can be `window`, `document` or `body`

```
(window:keypress)="doSomething($event)"
```

Comment: Ok, but if the event target is a `window`, a `document` or a `body`, how can I catch the scanned barcode ?

Comment: I don't know what exactly is going on when you scan a barcode or what the problem is you're running into. I assume you just get a series of keyboard events. Just combine them to a string. Is there some indication when a barcode scan process begins and when it ends?